# poisson and negative binomial

Tags: regression

I fit a poisson model but there was overdispersion. I fit a negative binomial model with same dataset. Does the conclusion suppose to be the same, or it could be different? For example, if poisson concluded significant, does the negative binomial also concluded significant?

Comment: You ask: if one distribution fits your data well, does this automatically imply that other distribution will fit it as well? Why would it?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no reason for this assumption. If you could make this assumption, there would be no need for two different methods.